# Detaching onSaveEntry events from craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry)?

Tags: plugin-development, events, yii

I have a plugin that does a bunch of stuff with external APIs `onSaveEntry` and then saves some of the gathered information back into the entry. I currently use `craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);` but I obviously create a loop.

I saw this answer ([Updating an entry after an event action within onSaveEntry](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10271/updating-an-entry-after-an-event-action-within-onsaveentry)) but since there is a nice [detachEventHandler method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#detachEventHandler-detail) I was wondering how to use it.

I tried hammering it with various combinations but I can't figure it out.

Right now, my plugin does this on `init` :

```
public function init(){
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
        craft()->rmsLink->rmsLinker($event);
    });
}
```

Then `rmsLinker`, which is in my `RmsLinkerService`, checks if the entry comes from the right canal and if so calls another function who is also in the `RmsLinkerService` like so :

```
$this->sendShowToRmsV1($settings, $entryAttributes, $entry);
```

It's then in `sendShowToRmsV1` that I need to do `craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry)` and prevent it from running the plugin all over again.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.